# Communicate between windows form and console

Tags: .net, winforms

Just wondering if anyone has an example of communicating from console app to windows form or vice versa.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean my communicating? Passing data to each other, calling methods remotely? Are both on a machine or are they to communicate via network communication?

Comment: Are they even different processes, or you just mean, e.g., reading from the console and writing to a form?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with Inter-Process Communication mechanisms (IPCs) or with writing/reading temp files. It depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

What form of communication are you talking about?

Information can be written to and read from a flat text file, XML files, a database etc.

There could be direct communication via sockets.

Or are you talking about one application "controlling" the other in some way?